# Handling a big slow incoming ajax response in real time

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to implement an AJAX request as part of a WebApplication.
The server side needs a long time to process the request completely, but it can output single items of the result very early.
So my intention is to have the client side render the parts of the response as soon as they arrive and not wait until the response is complete.

Here is my (simplified) server side code:

```
for (myObj o : db.results()) {
    // some rather slow operations at this place
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("tag1", o.tag1());
    j.put("tag2", o.tag2());
    System.out.println("Sending partial response: " + j.toString() );
    response.getWriter().write(j.toString());
    response.getWriter().flush();
}
```

My client side jquery request would look something like this:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: "queryURL",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("received " + data);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the success-function is only executed once the response is completed.
I couldn't find a way to execute a function for each time I call `response.getWriter().write()`.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think you need to operate server side and split the response in small pices.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you're asking, which is to effectively stream a response to the client.  I think multiple ajax calls is the best you'll get.

Comment: Go for websocket or for long-polling.

Comment: @pdegand59: thanks - the websocket hint looks promising.
@Archer/Alepac: yes - I thought about multiple ajax calls or splitting the response, but that involves a lot more overhead on the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to implement an "AJAX push" type of implementation can be very difficult.

A much simpler implementation of this could be to have your AJAX call start the process on the server, but have the server write the ongoing results to some file (i.e. as text, xml, whatever) as it's doing its thing.  Your AJAX success/done could be reading this file at some set interval (i.e. every 5 seconds) until it reaches the end-of-file.

It's not elegant... but it's simple and it works!

Comment: I don't really like that approach since it adds overhead on the serverside and is not very elegant (as you say). I think I'll try  websocket communication like suggested by pdegand59.

Comment: No worries, it was just another option to consider.  I've done it this way in the past and it tends to works well in certain situations (i.e. low-use components, very long processes, etc) while being very simple to implement.