# How to run external php script using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, json, cordova

I am trying to connect to a remote server and basically run my application off files on that server. I am able to connect to the server but I don't know how to execute the php files on that server. Here's my javascript function on my local directory which connects to the server:

```
    function test2(){
    $.getJSON("http://sampleserver.com/check.php?var=test&callback=?", {
    success:function(data){
        alert("Working"); }, 
    error: function() { 
    alert("Error"); 
}
});

}
```

This alerts "Working". Here's my check.php on the remote server:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'];
?>
```

Why is hello not being printed to the screen? How would I actually execute this script once I am connected?

Comment: i think your getJON syntax is wrong. have a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is just one example:

```
var url = '/m.profile_msg/0/send/';
var dataString = 'msg_body='+ msg_body;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        try {
            //var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data);
        } catch(e) {
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

And on the PHP side:

```
<?php
$xxarray = array('key' => 'value');
echo json_encode($xxarray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script IS already executing, but you're doing an AJAX call and simply alerting with your own message, you're not doing anything with the response, which would contain your hello text.

Comment: Is there a way to run the php script as in have it run on the screen in front of me instead of just getting text back?

Comment: Not with Ajax. Ajax can only accept one response. It can't split a long-running response into multiple callbacks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236475/handling-a-big-slow-incoming-ajax-response-in-real-time

Comment: I see, so what would be the way to remotely connect to the server and run scripts?

Answer (score 0):

To run remote scripts - try doing your ajax call to a PHP script and have the PHP script shell execute something. But I wouldn't wait for the reply - rather return a status code back to the mobile device saying that the script is running.